# If electrons are moving then why is it called electrostatics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, terminology, classical-electrodynamics, definition

We were doing an experiment in college where we plot equipotential lines of a point charge in space. To do this, we take a small nut, apply a certain voltage (say V) to it and take a probe at a different potential. Thus there is a P.D. between the points. We detect the points of equipotential using a multimeter connected to the probe.

From the equipotential lines, we draw the electric field lines which are perpendicular to the equipotential lines. Now, according to the manual these lines are **electrostatic** field lines. But, the field is created due to the moving electrons in the small nut. If electrons are moving, how can we call it electrostatics?

Specifically what is the difference between [electrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics) and electrodynamics?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101125/discussion-on-question-by-tatan-if-electrons-are-moving-then-why-is-it-called-el).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the change in magnetic field can be neglected, it is called **electrostatics**. In this case, you can define an electric potential $V$:
$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} = 0 \Rightarrow \mathbf{E} = - \nabla V$$

If the change in the electric field and electric current can be neglected, it is called **magnetostatics**. In this case, you can define a magnetic scalar potential $\phi$:

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t} = 0 \Rightarrow \mathbf{H} = - \nabla \phi$$

If you cannot make one of the above approximations, the full maxwell equations need to be solved. This case is called **electrodynamics**. This is also a more generic term.